# reading numbers into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, filereader

I'm trying to read numbers from a txt file into an array in ruby with some conditions. The text file input looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9;10 11 12
```

What I want to do is read the numbers up to ';', store them in array, execute a method on that array, and then clear the array and start reading from the semicolon again. Here you can see the execution of the program with the input seen above:

read [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> Execute method X -> [] Clear array -> [10 11 12] -> execute method X...

I think a variation of the following code would do the trick, but I don't know enough ruby to do this myself.

```
 a = []
 File.open('names.txt') do |f|
   f.each_line do |line|
     a << line.split.map(&:to_i)
   end
 end
```

Thanks for your help! This is for curiosity, not an assignment or anything else. I'm trying to build ruby skills by doing simple things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
f = File.read 'names.txt' 
f.split(';').each  do |set|
  method_x(set.split.map(&:to_i))
end
```

This assumes method_x takes an array as an arg.

Answer (score 3):

I would do as below :

```
File.readlines('a.txt',';').each do |string|
  ary = string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  method_x(ary)
end
```

You can put the line separator as `;`, as per the documentation [`readlines(name, sep=$/ [, open_args])`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) .

> Reads the entire file specified by name as individual lines, and returns those lines in an array. *Lines are separated by `sep`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read('names.txt').split(';').each { |x| the_function(x.split.map(&:to_i)) }
```

where `the_function` is your desired function